# UISwitch feels sticky. How do I toggle the UISwitch on press?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiswitch

Ive got this code and everything works correctly. But when I'm testing my app the switch is really hard to turn over on the UI.

```
-(IBAction)mySwitch:(UISwitch *)sender {
    if([_theSwitch isOn]){
        [_theSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
    }
    else if (![_theSwitch isOn]) {
        [_theSwitch setOn:YES animated:YES];
    }
}
```

is there any way that I can make it like the iOS 7 settings switches where it toggles on and off by button press rather than slide?

Comment: As far as I remember, all switches are like that - starting with the first iOS, you could flip them by a simple tap, with no code behind it.

Comment: Remove the code in mySwitch method and try testing again. That code doesn't make sense...

Comment: By the way, this whole piece of code can be replaced with `[_theSwitch setOn:![_theSwitch isOn] animated:YES]`

Comment: Thanks Tander. That worked. I'm new to iOS programming and for some reason i thought i needed to tell the switch what state it was in.

Comment: No problem. I will add my comment as an answer for you to accept. This helps others with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the code you've added. There is no reason to tell the switch which state it is in. It knows that info already. Remove all of that code and it should solve the issue.